# Does google cloud SQL instance use static IP Address by default?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When I created an sql instance in google cloud sql, it gave me an IP address. Will that IP address ever change, if so how to make it static so that it never changes?

Answer (score 4):

The [Google CloudSQL docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) indicate that the IP address will remain static until the instance is deleted:

> When you enable public IP for your instance, it is configured with a public, static IPv4 address.

This is consistent for [private IPs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, Your answer if very helpful, 5 stars!